# All of the faces in database have same pixel location coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
image = face_recognition.load_image_file('drive/MyDrive/Face-Recognition-Tensorflow-master/images/dicaprio.jpg')
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

for face_location in face_locations:`
    top, right, bottom, left = face_location`
    print("A face is located at pixel location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))`

return face_locations,image`
```

This is code:

```
database["leonardo dicaprio"] = face_img_to_encoding("my_images/dicaprio.jpg", FRmodel)
database["brad pitt"] = face_img_to_encoding("my_images/bradPitt1.jpg", FRmodel)
database["matt damon"] = face_img_to_encoding("my_images/mattDamon.jpg", FRmodel)
database["unknown"] = face_img_to_encoding("my_images/unknown.jpg", FRmodel)
```

**All of the coordinates** are the same:

```
A face is located at pixel location Top: 66, Left: 56, Bottom: 156, Right: 145
A face is located at pixel location Top: 66, Left: 56, Bottom: 156, Right: 145
A face is located at pixel location Top: 66, Left: 56, Bottom: 156, Right: 145
A face is located at pixel location Top: 66, Left: 56, Bottom: 156, Right: 145
```

Comment: I KNOW I USED MY DRIVE PATHS IN SECOND CODE HOWEVER I POSTED THE NORMAL CODE WITHOUT PATHS,

Comment: also i use google colab

Comment: Why would you expect them to each have different coordinates — why should they? It also seems like it would be a relatively easy thing to change / work-around if you need to…

Comment: you create `database` but you don't show how you use it. Maybe you don't use it. Or you asign the same image to all names. Or all your images have the same face.

Comment: because I'm going to do face-verification and all faces have different coordinates and need to be different to verify because code will verify from their pixel locations. and of course, my images are different from each other... i don't know if it use or not, however i wrote image to embedding codes too

Answer (score 0):

Would you think to use deepface? Its detectFace function returns detected and aligned faces.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
database = {}
database["brad pitt"] = DeepFace.detectFace("my_images/bradPitt1.jpg")
database["leonardo dicaprio"] = DeepFace.detectFace("my_images/dicaprio.jpg")
database["matt damon"] = DeepFace.detectFace("my_images/mattDamon.jpg")
database["unknown"] = DeepFace.detectFace("my_images/unknown.jpg")
```

BTW, it wraps several face detectors. SSD is the fastest but MTCNN is very strong at alignment.

```
detectors = ['mtcnn', 'opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib']
database["brad pitt"] = DeepFace.detectFace("my_images/bradPitt1.jpg", detector_backend = detectors[0])
```

On the other hand, if you want to run facial recognition, then you don't have to apply detection and alignment. DeepFaca handles it in the background.

```
resp = DeepFace.verify("my_images/bradPitt1.jpg", "my_images/dicaprio.jpg")
print(resp["verified"])
```